# How to check if my ball stopped rolling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to check when my ball stopped rolling (moving) for more then 5 seconds and then execute some code. I'm working on an android game and sometimes the ball gets stuck, the ball should be moving constantly so I want to check if it's moving and if it's not I need to respawn it.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Well your code should be moving it / stopping it. So when you stop it in your code run the code that says it is stopped.

Comment: Welcome to SO Infinity!  Please be careful with your tagging and please post some code of what you've tried so far.  1) I assume you're talking about the game engine, because the Unity inversion of control container probably has nothing to do with rolling balls.  Look at the tag wiki of the tag you picked.  2)  You picked JavaScript & C# tags, but JavaScript cannot support Unity (UnityScript is not JavaScript even though it's sometimes referred to as the same thing)

Answer (score 3):

Each time `Update` is called, you could check the magnitude of the object's velocity. If it's lower than a small amount (say 0.1 or something depending on your game's scale), add `Time.deltaTime` to a member variable, otherwise, set that variable to 0. If that variable is ever over 5, you know your object has been not moving (or close) for 5 seconds. Then execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple counter for count 5 seconds and check the gameObject.getComponent.velocity.magnitude;

And create a if and check this magnitude is smaller than your wanted level

Answer (score 0):

Put this as a C# script component onto your ball gameobject.

```
    public class MyBall : MonoBehaviour{
       private Transform _myTransform = null;
       private Vector3 _lastPosition = null;

       private void Awake(){
          _myTransform = transform;
          _lastPosition  = _myTransform.position;
       }

       private void Update(){
          if(_lastPosition == _myTransform.position){
             Debug.Log("Did not move");
          }else{
             Debug.Log("Moved");
          }
          _lastPosition = _myTransform.position;
       }
    }
```